# How to start loop.index after nth item

Tags: conditional-statements, twig

In a twig template showing a list of item names I use

```
{% for item in selection %}
  <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
  {% if loop.index % 4 == 0 %}
    <div class="xyz">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>          
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

to add a div after every 4th item. Is there a way to show a second div after every 4th item starting with the position "after #2"? So in the end I get the two divs alternating after every second item?

Comment: What do you mean with "after #2"? You want to display div A at the 4th item, div B at the 8th, div A at the 12th?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the divs alternating, let's say B after 2nd, A after the 4th, B after the 6th, A after the eight for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far easier to use the filter [`batch`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/batch.html) to create repeating structures in twig.
The following snippet will group the items by two, making it easier to alternate the extra div you want

```
{% for values in items|batch(2) %}
    {% for value in values %}
        <div>{{ value }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if loop.index0 is even %}
        <div class="xyz">Div 1</div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="xyz">Div 2</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ez3dqt)

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks! Now how would the line {% if loop.index0 is even %} look like if I want the divs to appear after every 4th (ord 8th od 12th) item?

Comment: You just change the batch amount, e.g. `batch(4)`