# Repeating structure with extra div and alternating content

Tags: conditional-statements, twig, repeat

Based on the solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72855239/5160621 I have a structure of repeating items with extra divs after every fourth item:

```
{% for values in items|batch(4) %}
    {% for value in values %}
        <div>{{ value }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if loop.index0 is even %}
        <div class="xyz">Div 1</div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="xyz">Div 2</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to display alternating contents in the second extra div, something like:

```
{% for values in items|batch(4) %}
    {% for value in values %}
        <div>{{ value }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if loop.index0 is even %}
        <div class="xyz">Div 1</div>
    {% else %}
        {% first appearance show: %}<div class="xyz">Div 2</div>
        {% then show: %}<div class="xyz">Div 3</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in a couple ways.

1. Use an extra "flag" variable

Just define the "flag" outside the `for`-loop.
You can toggle the value of the flag with the following snippet:

```
{% set flag = false %}
...
...
{% set flag = not flag %}
```

This will set the flag to `true` when the flag was `false` and vice versa.

```
{% set alternate = false %}

{% for values in items|batch(4) %}
    {% for value in values %}
        <div>{{ value }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if loop.index0 is even %}
        <div class="xyz">Div 1</div>
    {% else %}
        {% if alternate %}
            <div class="xyz">Div 3</div>        
        {% else %}
            <div class="xyz">Div 2</div>
        {% endif %}
        
        {% set alternate = not alternate %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ez3dqt/2)

---

2. Use the already existing `loop` variable

If you count out when the `div 3` should occur you'll notice the div should be displayed at the following 0-indexed indices:

```
3, 7, 11, 15, ...
```

But if you use `loop.index` instead of `loop.index0`, you can see each index is divisible by 4:

```
4, 8, 12, 16, ...
```

```
{% for values in items|batch(4) %}
    {% for value in values %}
        <div>{{ value }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if loop.index0 is even %}
        <div class="xyz">Div 1</div>
    {% else %}
        {% if loop.index is divisible by(4) %}
            <div class="xyz">Div 3</div>        
        {% else %}
            <div class="xyz">Div 2</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ez3dqt/3)

---

```
    | 1   | 2 |
1   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 1 |

    | 1   | 2 |
2   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 2 |
    
    | 1   | 2 |
3   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 1 | 
    
    | 1   | 2 |
4   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 3 |
    
    | 1   | 2 |
5   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 1 |

    | 1   | 2 |
6   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 2 |
    
    | 1   | 2 |
7   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 1 | 
    
    | 1   | 2 |
8   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 3 | 
    
    | 1   | 2 |
9   | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 1 |

    | 1   | 2 |
10  | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 2 |
    
    | 1   | 2 |
11  | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 1 | 
    
    | 1   | 2 |
12  | 3   | 4 |
    | DIV | 3 |
```

Comment: Just tested the first version and it works perfectly! Thanks alot!